# A commutative ring which has a group acting locally finitely on itself

Tags: commutative-algebra

The following definitions and proposition are motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219027/affine-algebraic-varieties-defined-over-a-not-necessarily-algebraically-closed).

All rings are assumed to be commutative and have identity elements.

**Definition 1**
Let $B$ be a ring.
Let $A$ be a subring of $B$.
An element $b$ of $B$ is called radical over $A$ if there exists an integer $n > 0$ such that $b^n \in A$.
$B$ is called radical over $A$ if every element of $B$ is radical over $A$.

**Definition 2**
Let $B$ be a ring.
Let $A$ be a subring of $B$.
Let $Aut(B/A)$ be the group of automorphisms of $B$ fixing every element of $A$.
Let $G$ be a group.
Let $\psi\colon G \rightarrow Aut(B/A)$ be a homomorphism.
Then $G$ acts on $B$ via $\psi$.
If every $G$-orbit is finite, we say $G$ acts on $B$ locally finitely over $A$.
We denote by $B^G$ the set of elemetns of $B$ which are invariant under $G$.
Clearly $B^G$ is a subring of $B$ containing $A$.

**Example**
Let $k$ be a field.
Let $\bar k$ be an algebraic closure of $k$.
Let $char(k)$ be the characteristic of $k$.
We define an integer $p$ as follows.

$p = char(k)$ if $char(k) > 0$.

$p = 1$ if $char(k) = 0$.

Let $k^{p^{-\infty}} = \{x \in \bar k$| there exists an integer $n \ge 0$ such that $x^{p^n} \in k\}$.

Let $A = k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, $B = \bar k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ be polynomial rings.
Let $G = Aut(\bar k/k)$.
Clearly $G$ acts on $B$ locally finitely over $A$ in the obvious way.
It is easy to see that $B^G = k^{p^{-\infty}}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.
Hence $B^G$ is radical over $A$.

**My question**
Is the following proposition true?
If yes, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $B$ be a Noetherian ring.
Let $A$ be a subring of $B$.
Let $G$ be a group acting on $B$ locally finitely over $A$.
Suppose $B^G$ is radical over $A$.
Let $p$ be a prime ideal of $A$.
Let $\Pi$ be the set of prime ideals of $B$ lying over $p$.
Then the following assertions hold.

1) $B$ is integral over $A$.

2) $\Pi$ is non-empty and finite and $G$ acts on $\Pi$ transitively.

3) [Going down theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down) holds on $B/A$.

4) Let $P$ be a prime ideal lying over $p$.
Then dim $A_p =$ dim $B_P$.

5) $\Pi$ is the set of minimal prime ideals containing $pB$.